# Set Different JS variable from PHP foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, foreach, laravel-5

I have very annoying problem, I need to display MySQL queries by using a PHP foreach loop but because of this when i try to set a javascript value for each of the items that are looped through it only selects either the first or last value it ignores the rest.

Here's what i've tried so far:

I have given an input a class and given it a value as well, this is within the for-each loop.

```
<input class="classs" value="{{ $item->id }}"/>
```

Next i have tried to access this from a js function, which is outside of the for-each loop.

```
    function addSubTaskToDatabase(){
    var itemId = $('.class').val();

        alert(itemId);
}
```

Problem is all this does is alert the last value in the for-each loop with that class, its the same for name and for id also.

Anyone know the fix..? all help is appreciated.

Comment: I can't see the foreach loop?

Comment: -_- the loop is in my code, the foreach loop is not the problem the problem is setting my JS variables do you want to see the loop regardless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var itemId = $('.class').val();
```

is going to select **all** elements on the page with that class.

You probably want a click function on the elements, and use `this` to access the currently-clicked item:

```
$('.class').click(function() {
    var itemId = $(this).val();
    alert(itemId);
});
```

Comment: worked like a charm thanks, last thing is i need to use this variable after an ajax request is triggered in a seperate function, is there a way to save this variable globally..?

Comment: i found a fix but it doesnt seem to be properly working, after settting that variable to hidden input i then call it from my ajax function but the data is not being passed in the request header? this is really off, its not even alerting the data

Answer (score 1):

To get all values you need an $().each loop

```
$('.class').each(function() {
    var itemId = $(this).val();        
    alert(itemId);
}
```

see https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: thank you both, i read through ceejayoz's answer first but this was great aswell thank you!